# Правильно ли составлено моё поздравление? Нет ли тавтологии?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Роман, привет дорогой! Ну что, я поздравляю тебя с днём рождения! Желаю тебе быть всегда и во всем лучшим, никогда не унывать, бодро и уверенно идти к своим поставленным целям, достигать их и оставаться всегда весёлым и жизнерадостным человеком. А также я тебе желаю огромного счастья, крепкого здоровья и финансовых высот.

Answer (score 1):

Перед "дорогой" нужна запятая, это второе обращение: [Нацкорпус](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9).

Сочетание "свои цели" уже подразумевает то, что они "поставленные". Похоже на плеоназм. Здесь "поставленным" не звучит вместе со "своим".

"Человеком" можно опустить, понятно, что он не эльф или т.п. Это слово не несёт никакой информации, оно избыточно.

"Я тебе" лучше опустить. Так лучше звучит.

Answer (score 0):

Формально, не унывать и быть веселым и жизнерадостным не одно и то же, так как можно не унывать и при этом быть нейтральным.

Comment: Да, всё в порядке.